# Can you derive the surface area formula for a spherical triangle from the angle of sum formula of a spherical triangle?

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

*Despite the long title, my question is very short and clear:*

**Can you not just derive the surface area formula for a spherical triangle from the angle of sum formula of a spherical triangle with two simple equations?**

---

The angle of sum formula is as follows: **π+(T∆ABC/r^2)=A+B+C**

And can I not just subtract pi and divide with r^2 on both sides of the equation and get the surface area formula for a spherical triangle; 
**T∆ABC= (A+B+C- π)∙r2**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the area of a spherical triangle is proportional to the scaled angle excess. $$(A+B+C-\pi)\cdot r^2$$ is correct, although I've never before seen the area denoted with a formula symbol like $T\triangle ABC$.

I find [the Wikipedia section on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry#Area_and_spherical_excess) to be less clear than what I'd have expected.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, MvG.

I know that I have denoted it a little weird, but that is the way that it is denoted in my book.

And yes, the Wikipedia page isn't excactly the most reliable.